# How to check if exe is running on terminal session from the server

Tags: delphi, service, terminal

I'm creating a update program that will copy over updated .exe files. It needs to check if any of the .exes are running in a terminal session. If the .exes are running it will kill them. This will be a service that is running on the server with admin rights. The code needs to be in Delphi any one have any thoughts on this?

Comment: I'm not sure about the capibilities of Delphi, but it should be as simple as grabbing your running process list, enumerating through it, and doing a literal check agianst the process name.

Answer (score 9):

If you check these SO question I believe your question will be answered.
They may not be for delphi specifically but the approved answer for the second one provides a link to the MSDN website.

[how-to-programmatically-tell-if-the-terminal-server-service-is-running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110120/how-to-programmatically-tell-if-the-terminal-server-service-is-running)

[how-do-i-tell-if-my-application-is-running-in-an-rdp-session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295415/how-do-i-tell-if-my-application-is-running-in-an-rdp-session)

Or another quick search on the web revealed this code snippet.  (This is not my code)

```
function ProcessIdToSessionId(dwProcessId: DWORD; pSessionId: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall; external 'kernel32.dll';

function GetSessionIdfromProccessId(const processId: DWORD; var sessionId: DWORD): boolean;
begin
    result:=ProcessIdToSessionId(processId, DWORD(@sessionId));
end;

function GetCurrentSessionId: DWORD;
begin
    if not GetSessionIdfromProccessId(GetCurrentProcessId,result) then
        result:=0;
end;
```

It seems as if the result from GetCurrentSessionid <> 0 then your running under TS.

HTH.

Answer (score 3):

There are a group of APIs that can enumerate and retrieve sessions and processes in sessions.  The two you may need are [WTSEnumerateSessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383833.aspx) and [WTSEnumerateProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383831.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The processes have to be killed anyway, whether they run under terminal session or not.
Can you please clarify - why do you need this info?

The best way to kill process is to use "pskill" until from sysexternals.
Just use exec from your Delphi code.

Comment: I didn't want to call pskill if the process was not running

Comment: pskill won't crash on that. there is no problem to call it on non-existing process.